# Newbie need help ASP-HTML

Tags: html, asp-classic

appreciate if you could help me(newbies).

I have "page.asp" from a server with the following body code:

```
<body>
    <input id="Value1" value='<% =Value1 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value2" value='<% =Value2 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value3" value='<% =Value3 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value4" value='<% =Value4 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value5" value='<% =Value5 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value6" value='<% =Value6 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value7" value='<% =Value7 %>' type="hidden"/>
    <input id="Value8" value='<% =Value8 %>' type="hidden"/>



    <h1 id="myHeader">[<% =Value1 %>] [<% =Value2 %>] [<% =Value3 %>] [<% =Value4 %>] [<% =Value5 %>] [<% =Value6 %>] [<% =Value7 %>] [<% =Value8 %>]</h1>


 </body>
```

Question: How should i code html page reads "page.asp" value?

-Newbies-

Comment: What value are you trying to read?

Comment: the input value in page.asp @IrishGeek82

Comment: His question seemed quite clear to me. This "putting on hold" thing is a bit extreme. He said he is a newbie. From my perspective as an expert with Classic ASP, he asked as clearly as he could, given that he is a beginner. Isn't one of the points of this site to HELP BEGINNERS? How about giving them benefit of the doubt?

Answer (score 1):

The values can be read from your respective fields using (most likely, in your case):

```
<%
Dim myValue1
myValue1 = Request.Form("Value1")
%>
```

If you're expecting a `QueryString` then you'll need...

```
<%
Dim myValue1
myValue1 = Request.QueryString("Value1")
%>
```

You can then work with the variables as you like within your code...

```
<%
Dim myV1, myV2, answer
myV1 = Request.QueryString("Value1")
myV2 = Request.QueryString("Value2")
answer = myV1 + myV2
Response.Write(answer)
%>
```